# chart data on 24hr X axis using recharts, chart.js, I don't mind what

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, recharts

I am struggling for days now trying to figure out how to display my data on a 24hrs x axis.

This is my data:

```
"glucoseMesures": [
        {
            "glucose": 85,
            "date": "2015-06-12T00:49:50+00:00"
        },
        {
            "glucose": 77,
            "date": "2015-06-12T07:09:03+00:00"
        },
        {
            "glucose": 58,
            "date": "2015-06-12T11:23:15+00:00"
        },
        {
            "glucose": 110,
            "date": "2015-06-12T16:00:58+00:00"
        },
        {
            "glucose": 97,
            "date": "2015-06-12T19:35:01+00:00"
        },
        {
            "glucose": 142,
            "date": "2015-06-12T21:15:50+00:00"
        }
    ]
```

I am able to plot them to Recharts and Chart.js but I cannot seem to to plot them to time order. With Recharts I was able to plot them to time order but then cannot amend the x axis labels to display this:

```
labels: ["00:00", "03:00", "06:00", "09:00", "12:00", "15:00", "18:00", "21:00", "00:00"]
```

All I need is an X axis with the label times, then the data plotting to the Glucose time, sorry I have jsfiddle made yet. I am using react.

What I need: 
[image]

Comment: Hi how have you been able to put timeframes on x axis in recharts?I've been trying to plot 24 hrs in 1hr interval on x-axis but I can't find anything on the docs

Comment: I went over to Chart.js and used the stepSize prop in the end, it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this quite easily with Chart.js by using the built-in [`time` axis](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html).

The trick is to supply the correct configuration values to the x-axis:

- `unit: hour` - the ticks are based on the hour.
- `stepSize: 3` - the ticks are shown for every third hour.
- `min: "2015-06-12T00:00"` - the ticks start from the beginning of the day.
- `max: "2015-06-13T00:00"` - the ticks end at the beginning of the next day.

As long as the dataset you provide is correctly sorted (in sequential datetime order) then you should get a result like in this snippet:

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      data: [{
          t: "2015-06-12T00:49:50+00:00",
          y: 85
        },
        {
          t: "2015-06-12T07:09:03+00:00",
          y: 77
        },
        {
          t: "2015-06-12T11:23:15+00:00",
          y: 58,
        },
        {
          t: "2015-06-12T16:00:58+00:00",
          y: 110
        },
        {
          t: "2015-06-12T19:35:01+00:00",
          y: 97
        },
        {
          t: "2015-06-12T21:15:50+00:00",
          y: 142
        }
      ]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: "time",
        time: {
          unit: "hour",
          stepSize: 3,
          min: "2015-06-12T00:00",
          max: "2015-06-13T00:00",
          displayFormats: {
            hour: 'HH:mm'
          }
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
```